# Django: ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoIP2'

Tags: django, geodjango

I am trying to set up `geoip2` for GeoDjango as per [the instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/#geoip-path).

For some reason the wrapper isn't importing the function. It worked before I downloaded the databases and pointed to them in my settings, but for some reason now I can't load `GeoIP2` (even when I comment out the line in `settings.py`). How should I troubleshoot this?

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import geoip2
>>>
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoIP2'
>>>
```

EDIT: I can see the `GeoIP2` function correctly listed in the source file (which I haven't modified). What could possibly be preventing it from loading?

I am running Django 1.11.4

If I import `django.contrib.gis.geoip2` this is it's `__path__` property:

```
>>> geoip2.__path__
['C:\\Users\\Adam\\Envs\\otherlane\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\gis\\geoip2']
```

Comment: what django version?

Comment: Django v 1.11.4

Comment: did you install geoip2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) is Deprecated since **version 1.9** in favor of `django.contrib.gis.geoip2`, which supports IPv6 and the GeoLite2 database format.

If you have a django < 1.9, use instead

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
```

Comment: Good looking out, unfortunately that isn't my issue. I'm running 1.11.4

Comment: did you install geoip2?

Comment: Yes, it is installed and I can successfully import it directly with `import geoip2`

Comment: virtualenv is active, and it's there with `pip freeze`??

Comment: I run `django==1.11.11` and just installed the `geoip2`, and tried to import the django packaged, it worked

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me at first too..I've tried reinstalling

Comment: do also for all the packages, `django`, `geoip`, and try again

Comment: Still no luck. I'm doing everything with the same virtual environment

Comment: Um, so I had a forward slash instead of a back slash in my GEOIP_PATH setting. I corrected it and it works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: install `geoip`, and then I was able to do `from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2` well.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed by installing it through pip package `geoip2==2.9.0`

```
pip install geoip2==2.9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

just run the command pip install geoip2 then it will work fine...

Answer (score 1):

Double check your `GEOIP_PATH`. And my I remind you that Windows requires back slashes not forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error and couldn't resolve it after multiple attempts.
Since it was working on one of my system, I found one difference, When you install geoip2 via pip it also installs maxminddb. The system on which it was working, maxminddb version was 1.5.4 and the one on which it was not working it was maxminddb==2.0.0
so finally I did
`pip install maxminddb==1.5.4`
and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it this way

```
from geoip2 import geolite2
```